# Format specifies type 'unsigned short' but the argument has type 'int'

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have a method that scans a string, converting any new lines to `<br>` for HTML. The line in question is:

```
NSCharacterSet *newLineCharacters = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:
          [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\n\r%C%C%C%C", 0x0085, 0x000C, 0x2028, 0x2029]];
```

Xcode gives me a warning here:

```
Format specifies type 'unsigned short' but the argument has type 'int'
```

It's recommending that I change all `%C` to `%d`, however that turns out to break the function. What is the correct way to do this, and why is Xcode recommending the wrong thing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One option is to cast your arguments to unsigned short: i.e. `(unsigned short)0x0085` etc

But if you're looking for newlines, you should just use the newline character set. This is "Unicode compliant":`[ NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet ]`

**edit**

Revisiting this question: If you are trying to separate an NSString/CFString by line breaks, you should probably use `-[ NSString getLineStart:end:contentsEnd:forRange:]`.

Answer (score 2):

Using the canned character sets as @nielsbot suggests is definitely the way to go when there's one that matches your app's needs.

But as far as writing a string literal with Unicode codepoints in it, you don't need `-stringWithFormat:`, you can just use Unicode escapes:

```
NSCharacterSet *aCharSet = [NSCharacterSet
  characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"\u2704\u2710\u2764"];
```