# Xcode suggests to replace %C with %d

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ios5, automatic-ref-counting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Format specifies type ‘unsigned short’ but the argument has type ‘int’](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12117709/format-specifies-type-unsigned-short-but-the-argument-has-type-int)

I am using the NSString Html category at https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWFeedParser/blob/master/Classes/NSString%2BHTML.m

Xcode gives me this suggestion

[image]

Should i agree and replace it ?

[image]

Comment: It would be better to cast each argument to `(char)` or use the UTF hex encoding for the characters, between single quotes.

Comment: If you want to print those values as characters, then not, and you should cast to `(unsigned short)` instead.

Comment: sorry i was mistaken your question and answered

Comment: The library does not print those character it used them for below purpose. to replace with a space

// Replace with a space

if ([scanner scanCharactersFromSet:newLineAndWhitespaceCharacters intoString:NULL]) {
   if (result.length > 0 && ![scanner isAtEnd]) // Dont append space to beginning or end of result
    [result appendString:@" "];
  }

Comment: @HotLicks i would appreciate it if you can write your suggested solution in the answer.

Comment: FYI - you can replace the 0x000C with `\f` in the format string.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to cast each argument to (char) or use the UTF hex encoding for the characters, between single quotes.

Comment: But %C is for `unichar` aka `unsigned short`.

Comment: ... and casting 0x2028 to `char` ??

Comment: Yep, probably should be `unichar`, not `char`.

Comment: Better would be `'\x2028'`, with no cast.